# Quicktime format not an export option?

Tags: rendering, export

[image]

As you can see by the screen shot I took, when I choose the File format I want to export my animation in, Quicktime is not an option. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Quicktime is a container.

On version 2,79 you have to choose FFmpeg video to reveal the **encoding** options.

There you can choose quicktime as Container and the codec.

[image]