# why there are just 4 options for rendering animation?

Tags: rendering, animation

I need to render animation and there are only 4 options to render. 
I select png. at the output and then are only AVI raw, AVI jpeg, frame server and FFmpeg video options. I want QuickTime or another format.

what shall I do? I have the latest version installed.
it runs on an iMac with graphics Radeon Pro 580 8192 MB and

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quicktime format not an export option?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101194/quicktime-format-not-an-export-option) and [Blender 2.79 I only get four video output options](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82962/blender-2-79-i-only-get-four-video-output-options)

Answer (score 1):

Those settings actually exist under FFmpeg video. The options for containers and codecs are under the encoding options just under the output options

[image]